# Looking for products to perform TermStore synchronization with external data source (2010)

Tags: 2010, term-store, sync, term, oracle

**I apologize if this question is too vague or is missing important information, I'm a co-op student and have zero experience with SharePoint.

I have been tasked with finding and analysing options to synchronize Term Stores to Oracle reference tables. Through my research I could only find two products to accomplish this, [TermSync](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/products/managed-metadata-synchronization-solution/) and [MatchPoint](http://www.colygon.com/newslist/6112013preview-matchpoint-term-store-importer-for-sharepoint). Are there any other products that can accomplish this task? Also is something like this feasible to do manually/custom? We are already using BDLC for SharePoint lists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you check [this (Enterprise class auto-classification and taxonomy management market leading solutions))](http://www.conceptsearching.com/wp/). they are claiming that they are best.

Comment: I have sent them an email with some questions, though I fear they may suffer from the same issue as MatchPoint where they offer way more functionality than we need, still thank you for the answer. Any other suggestions from anyone else would still be greatly appreciated.